# Abort heavy apache request when receive new one

Tags: php, ajax, apache, http

I'm developing a website with php and apache. with an interval user's browser send an ajax request to the server that It's response takes some times... (It's heavy!). 
after this req an until it's response received, not any link works for that user.

How can I handle this request and abort the first one when server get the second?

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore the first"? Do you want to abort the request if you get a new request? What if you keep getting new requests? Wouldn't that mean that the heavy operation would never be finished?

Comment: I have a feeling that this issue is related to session file locking rather than some heavy processes.

Comment: @magnus A req take about 30 sec. time to answered. during this time, if the use want to leave this page to an other one, he cannot. He should wait for that first req...